# Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to call a form

```
public partial class MenuForm : Form
    {

        Ventanas v = new Ventanas();
        EnfermoRep reporteEnfermo = new EnfermoRep();
        public MenuForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void rptEnfermo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            v.CargarVentana(reporteEnfermo, this.panel1);
        }
    }
```

but when I run it,marks "Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown" when i'm instancing the "EnfermoRep".

This is the other class

```
public partial class EnfermoRep : Form
    {

        Ventanas v = new Ventanas();
        MenuForm menuForm = new MenuForm();
        public EnfermoRep()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void EnfermoRep_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'bd.Enfermo' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.EnfermoTableAdapter.Fill(this.bd.Enfermo);

            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }

        private void btnVolver1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            v.CargarVentanas(menuForm, this.enfermoRep);
        }
    }
```

And also i'm using this so I can alternate between panels in just one form:

```
class Ventanas
    {
        public void CargarVentana(object sonform, Panel panel)
        {
            panel.Controls.Clear();
            Form fh = sonform as Form;
            fh.TopLevel = false;
            fh.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            fh.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            panel.Controls.Add(fh);
            panel.Tag = fh;
            fh.Show();
        }
}
```

In every form I make, I put a panel dock in container, so I can call it with The "Ventana" class

Any idea how to solve that error. Thanks! :D

Comment: You create a `EnfermoRep` in the `MenuForm` and then you create a `MenuForm` in the `EnfermoRep`, that's an infinite loop of creating objects.

Comment: It would be easier to people to help you if the names were in English - StackOverflow is for questions in English. "CargarVentanas" translates as "LoadWindows". Without that comprehension, it is harder for people to understand what you are doing, and therefore harder for them to help you. "EnfermoRep" google translate gives as "Sick rep"; but I would guess it probably should be "Close Report"? But I shouldn't have to work this hard to help you. Or to put it another way, I would choose to spend my time answering a question where I don't have to translate things.

Comment: I will do in next time, thanks for the advice! c: And yes "Enfemorep" is a form which contains a report of all the people sick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I'm not wrong, but a simple fix (possibly not a good one) would be:

```
public partial class MenuForm : Form
{

    Ventanas v = new Ventanas();
    EnfermoRep reporteEnfermo;
    public MenuForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        reporteEnfermo = new EnfermoRep(this);
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void rptEnfermo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        v.CargarVentana(reporteEnfermo, this.panel1);
    }
} 

public partial class EnfermoRep : Form
{

    Ventanas v = new Ventanas();
    MenuForm menuForm;
    public EnfermoRep(MenuForm MF)
    {
        menuForm = MF;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void EnfermoRep_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.EnfermoTableAdapter.Fill(this.bd.Enfermo);

        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }

    private void btnVolver1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        v.CargarVentanas(menuForm, this.enfermoRep);
    }
}
```

Not sure though if that will resolve your problem overall, but it does get rid of the stackoverflow. It is just a small change. You just pass your MenuForm as a parameter instead of creating a new one inside of the EnfermoRep class. In this solution it is neccessary to create the MenuForm first. It is not difficult to make changes neccessary to be able to create the EnfermoRep first. I will leave that as a task ;)

Answer (score 1):

When you construct `MenuForm`, this code runs:

```
EnfermoRep reporteEnfermo = new EnfermoRep();`
```

When you construct `EnfermoRep`, this code runs:

```
MenuForm menuForm = new MenuForm();
```

You end up recursing forever.  If you look at your Stack panel, you will see the stack creating a `EnfermoRep` and then a `MenuForm` and repeating that sequence forever.  You'll need to detangle your code.  Generally, if you want to run both forms at the same time, create the two forms somewhere else (in your `Main` routine, for example) and then run them from there.

Comment: Yep as the comment above and you say, I'm doing that, but it's because I want to come back from EnfermoRep to MenuForm.

Comment: MenuForm Calls to EnfermoRep, and I added I button in EnfermoRep so I can return to the MenuForm, but I just don't know how to